# Time of flight of projectile from launch to landing

Tags: projectile-motion

The formula below is the time of flight ( time of whole journey from launch(0,0) to landing (×,y) ) of a projectile whose initial vertical position is above the point of impact.

[image]

I am trying to understand how the right side of the equation is derived. For instance, how do I come up with 2gy$_0$ ?

$\frac{d}{v.cos(\theta)}$ = $\frac{v.sin(\theta)+\sqrt{\left(v.sin(\theta)\right)^2 +2gy_0}}{g}$

Where

g = gravitational acceleration

y$_0$ = initial vertical position (h)

d = entire horizontal distance or range of the flight from launch to landing

v = velocity

$\theta$ = initial launch angle

Thanks

Comment: You can find the proof in any good physics book. Also refer to [Projectile_motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

Comment: This was actually from wikipedia. It didn't show how the right hand side is derived, and I am unable to find an online resource for this particular derivation.

Comment: Ah ok! I've added a hint to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let consider at first the equation of motion in vertical direction that is

- $y(t)=h+v_0 \sin\theta \cdot t-\frac12 g t^2$

then by the condition $y(t)=0$ find the time of landing $t_{L}$.

Finally use that to find x of landing by

- $d=x(t_{L})=v_0 \cos \theta \cdot t_{L}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I can now see that it involves the use of quadratic formula as shown here https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/two-dimensional-motion/modal/v/launching-and-landing-on-different-elevations

Comment: Yes exactly! Let me know if you need some more information. Bye